# SQL - Use variable in Join Statement

Tags: sql, declare

I have a question regarding some SQL statement. I'm not the most advanced person in SQL and inherited something from a former colleague. In the first statement I'm declaring a variable I can insert into the LEFT Join at the bottom but it throws me an error saying invalid object name. What am I doing wrong? Also would someone be so kind to explain to me what the @rows statement does? Am I checking here whether this months table is empty and if yes, then I use last months table?

```
DECLARE
    @thismonth NVARCHAR(6) = CONVERT(nvarchar(6),FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyyMM')),
    @lastmonth NVARCHAR(6) = CONVERT(nvarchar(6),FORMAT(DATEADD(month,-1,getdate()),'yyyyMM')),
    @thismonthtable NVARCHAR(128),
    @lastmonthtable NVARCHAR(128),
    @rows INT,
    @table NVARCHAR(128),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @thismonthtable = N'tablename' + @thismonth + N'_V3';
SET @lastmonthtable = N'tablename' + @lastmonth + N'_V3';
SET @rows = (SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(B.rows),0) AS [rows]
                FROM        sys.objects A
                INNER JOIN sys.partitions B ON A.object_id = B.object_id
                WHERE       A.type = 'U' and A.Name = LEFT(@thismonthtable,LEN(@thismonthtable)-3));
SET @table = CASE @rows
                WHEN 0 THEN @lastmonthtable
                ELSE @thismonthtable
                END
;

bla bla 

LEFT JOIN [XXX].[XXX].[' + @table + N']
```

I'm not super familiar  with this but @table without the rest also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ...why not just use dynamic-SQL instead of faffing around with `sys.objects`?

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of a badly designed and denormalised structure - there is a table per-month?! `@rows` is getting the rowcount of the specified table. you can't use variables as part of DML, you'll need to build and execute the statement dynamically, but I would take a step back.

Comment: @Stu To be fair, table-per-month is reasonable in ETL scenarios - or when data schemas change over time and people want to preserve historical data as-is ("as-was"?).

Comment: @Dai to be clear, dynamic-SQL, are you thinking `openquery`?  I was thinking maybe a View to wrap `[XXX].[XXX].[' + @table + N']` or maybe a Table Function might make the syntax easier for Fishsupporter

Comment: @tgolisch No, I mean _good ol'_ `sp_executesql`: https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I agree that the approach that @Dai is talking about is the simplest/quickest

Comment: @Dai Yes I agree to be fair that is a valid scenario and it's not uncommon, it does though make handling the data and reporting more complicated depending on how it's used, possibly partitioning might be used instead.